# Parameter with quotes within a query not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So I have this code:

```
 $infos['title'] = addslashes("Le Roi D'Australie");
 $offer = get_page_by_title($infos['title'], ARRAY_A, 'post');
```

This doesn't work whereas all the other post I have with no quote are actually working well.

Do you have an answer ? get_page_by_title should escape the title for me..
I must have miss something.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[wpdb->prepare](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) (used by [`get_page_by_title`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_page_by_title/)) *already* correctly prevents SQL injection when the parameterized form is used.

> All data in SQL queries must be SQL-escaped before the SQL query is executed to prevent against SQL injection attacks. ***The `prepare` method performs this [SQL-escaping] functionality for WordPress.***

Simply *remove* the `addslashes` call as it adds in a useless/extra slash that makes the query fail. It is valid SQL in either case (thanks to `prepare`), but it uses a now-over-slashed-value.

Then [read through this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?lq=1) to see why addslashes is *never* correct for SQL. (Best solution is to only use `wpdb->prepare`, or similar placeholder models, and methods that use it.)